# Run Crontab in Linux when a new file created in a directory

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have a set a crontab in my ubuntu 16.04 to fetch data from `/var/www/html/import/IMPORT-DATA.CSV` through a PHP script.

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron/import-csv.php
```

Its working fine, and after fetching the data my PHP script will delete the file (`/var/www/html/import/IMPORT-DATA.CSV`).

I want to set up a script in Linux (either a crontab or something else) which can run my `PHP script` once if the `IMPORT-DATA.CSV` file uploaded in the directory `/var/www/html/import/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways I can think of off the top of my head:

1. Find out if your FTP server can be configured to trigger a script for you. (For example, pureftpd's upload-script function https://linux.die.net/man/8/pure-uploadscript , not all FTP server software can do this.)
2. Setup an `inotify` watcher perhaps with `inotify-tools.` (You could create your own with PHP as well ([inotify extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php)), but that would probably negate any performance gain since you'd have an instance of PHP constantly running.)

**And a sort-of third option:** If you're merely wanting to avoid invoking PHP just to see that the file isn't there - you can chain to a bash file test before invoking your PHP script. The cron call still runs every 5 minutes, but only calls PHP if the file is there. (Note that I haven't exactly tested this, but pretty confident it would work.)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/5 * * * * test -e /var/www/html/import/IMPORT-DATA.CSV && php /var/www/html/cron/import-csv.php
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can distribute your tasks is 3 different scripts and chain them in cron.

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron/import-csv.php && /var/www/html/cron/YOUR_PERFORM_SOME_OTHER_TASK_PHP_SCRIPT && /var/www/html/cron/YOUR_DELETE-CSV-SCRIPT.php
```

`&&` will make sure that, the next script runs only if the previous
 ran sucessfully.

Comment: Dear @sulabh chaturvedi, I think my question is not clear, will explain once again. The requirement is some one will upload a csv file through FTP into the `/var/www/html/import/` directory, then a php programe should run and fetch the data from the CSV and store it in a DB, then the php script should delete the CSV file in that location.

For this we set a crontab in linux which will run the php script every 5 minutes. everything working fine, no issues.

But i am trying to setup a script in linux or modify crontab which will run the php script only when a new file is uploaded there.

Comment: So, your script should first check whether or not file is uploaded. If yes, perform actions as needed else exit the script.  Though I ain't any php expert, however, I think you could use file_exists function in your script, if that returns true perform action as needed else exit the script. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php]

Comment: Dear @Sulabh Chaturvedi, my php script is running if file is found in that location, as you said i already used file_exists function.

See the Crontab is running the PHP script every 5 minutes. so think it will be run 288 times in a day right? but the person may upload CSV file twice or thrice in a day but we are not sure at what time he will be upload, so around 24 hours he will upload any time. so why the php script should run 288  times in a day?

Comment: so I am trying to run my PHP script after immediately the file is uploaded. So, I am looking a script or something else like a setup in Linux that will execute my PHP script after a file is uploaded to that directory.

Comment: Since, you don't know what time the file is uploaded. you'll have to keep checking in certain interval whether a file is uploaded or not. Also, until a file is not uploaded your script pity much doing nothing but, just check of file exists of not. Why do you think this is a problem ?

Comment: So, if the person upload that CSV file in three times, then my script will run only three times in a day.

Comment: Okay, so, is the FTP auto or manual ? If its auto, you can set a flag from FTP script to trigger your script, that way script would run only thrice a day

Comment: Whom so ever it may concern, please provide reasons to downvote the answer. I assume you have read whole conversation here in the comments section.

Comment: I didn't downvote, also I am not seeing any down vote.

Comment: someone did that before. The comment was meant for that someone.